# Is it possible to change the way form looks in angular-formly in terms of layout?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

In angular formerly we pass the array with fields and it generates the form in its std. way or layout. but if want to change its look or layout .Is it possible and how?

Comment: numerous ways using classes, using groups and using templates ... read the docs and look at the examples

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do advanced layout using field groups as in [this example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/advanced-layout). I also recommend you learn the fundamentals of angular-formly [here](http://learn.angular-formly.com).